# Self Study Set Operation Probability Theory Consistency

Tags: probability-theory, parameter-estimation

I am having difficulties understanding an argument related to the consistency of an estimator. The argument is:

$$
\{A \leq \frac{\epsilon}{2}\} \cap \{B \leq \frac{\epsilon}{2}\} \subseteq \{A + B \leq \epsilon\}
$$

where no further information about $A, B$ is provided, however the context is that if $\hat{\theta}_{n,i} = (\hat{\theta}_{n,1},...,\hat{\theta}_{n,p})$ is a consistent estimator with $p$ components for $\theta_{n,i} = (\theta_{n,1},...,\theta_{n,p})$ :
$$
\mathbb{P}(||\hat{\theta}_{n,i} - \theta_{n,i}||_2 > \epsilon) \leq \sum_{i=1}^p \mathbb{P}(|\hat{\theta}_{n,i} - \theta_{n,i}| > \epsilon/\sqrt{p})
$$

Now:

$$
\mathbb{P}(||\hat{\theta}_{n,i} - \theta_{n,i}||_2 > \epsilon) = \mathbb{P}( \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^p(\hat{\theta}_{n,i} - \theta_{n,i})^2} > \epsilon) 
$$

and:
$$
\mathbb{P}( \sum_{i=1}^p(\hat{\theta}_{n,i} - \theta_{n,i})^2 > \epsilon^2) \leq \sum_{i=1}^p\mathbb{P}( (\hat{\theta}_{n,i} - \theta_{n,i})^2 > \frac{\epsilon^2}{p}) = \sum_{i=1}^p\mathbb{P}( |(\hat{\theta}_{n,i} - \theta_{n,i})| > \frac{\epsilon}{\sqrt{p}})
$$

where the first argument for p values was uesed:
$$
\cap^{i=1,...,p}\{A_i \leq \frac{\epsilon}{p}\} \subseteq \{\sum_{i=1}^p A_i \leq \epsilon\}
$$

Let $\hat{\theta}_{n,i} - \theta_{n,i} =: Z_i$, then why is:

$$
\mathbb{P}( \sum_{i=1}^p Z_i^2 > \epsilon^2) \leq \sum_{i=1}^p\mathbb{P}( Z_i^2 > \frac{\epsilon^2}{p}) = \sum_{i=1}^p\mathbb{P}( |Z_i| > \frac{\epsilon}{\sqrt{p}})
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit**:

It is direct that:$$\omega\in\left\{A\leq\frac12\epsilon\right\}\cap\left\{B\leq\frac12\epsilon\right\}\iff A(\omega)\leq\frac{\epsilon}2\text{ and }B(\omega)\leq\frac{\epsilon}2$$$$\implies A(\omega)+B(\omega)\leq\epsilon\iff (A+B)(\omega)\leq\epsilon\iff\omega\in\{A+B\leq\epsilon\}$$

---

Taking complements we also have:$$\{A+B>\epsilon\}\subseteq\left\{A>\frac12\epsilon\right\}\cup\left\{B>\frac12\epsilon\right\}$$

or more generally: $$\left\{\sum_{i=1}^p A_i>\epsilon\right\}\subseteq\bigcup_{i=1}^p\left\{A_i>\frac1p\epsilon\right\}$$implying:$$\Pr\left(\left\{\sum_{i=1}^p A_i>\epsilon\right\}\right)\leq\sum_{i=1}^p\Pr\left(\left\{A_i>\frac1p\epsilon\right\}\right)$$
does that help?

Comment: Thx for the reply, I understand the complement argument, but why is: $\{A \leq \frac{\epsilon}{2}\} \cap \{B \leq \frac{\epsilon}{2}\} \subseteq \{A + B \leq \epsilon\}$?

Comment: That is direct:$$\omega\in\{A\leq\epsilon/2\}\cap\{B\leq\epsilon/2\}\iff A(\omega)\leq\epsilon/2\text{ and }B(\omega)\leq\epsilon/2$$$$\implies A(\omega)+B(\omega)\leq\epsilon\iff\omega\in\{A+B\leq\epsilon\}$$

Comment: aaaaaaaaah. thank you so much!

Comment: You are welcome.